# yii2 Kartik file input work only after refresh page

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2

I am using kartik file input widget in some forms in a yii2 project. when in the browser one of forms be opened, the kartik element for first time appear nothing and kartik element appear only after refresh page.

I used kartik like this.

```
echo $form->field($contentModel, 'fileContents')->widget(FileInput::classname(), 
                    [
                    'language' => 'fa',
                    'options' => [
                        'id' => 'fileContents',
                        'multiple' => false,
                        'layoutTemplates' => 'modal',
                    ],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'showUpload' => false,
                        'showPreview' => false,

                        'maxFileCount' => 1,
                        'maxFileCount' => 1,
                        'maxFileSize' => \backend\modules\YiiFileManager\models\File::MAX_PDF_FILE_SIZE,
                    ]
                ])->label('', ['class' => '']);
```

I call my view form by follow codes:

```
$(document).on('click', '.handle-modal-click', function () {
     modalContentUrl = $(this).attr('modalContentUrl');
     title = $(this).attr('title');
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         async: false,
         url: modalContentUrl,
         data: {modal_text: $('#modal_text').val()},
         success: function (msg) {
             $('.modal-body').html(msg);
             $('.modal-header #headerTitle').html(title);
             $('#modal').modal('show');
         },
     });
});
```

Comment: are there any error on the console when you load it for the first time, and add your complete view if possible. and when you load it for the first time is your form being loaded via ajax call?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam thanks for your attention, console is clear without any errors and I am using ajax to call form.
the view form is in the modal and is called as follow

Comment: in your controller action where your ajax call is routed using the value in `modalContentUrl ` how are you loading the view you should use `renderAjax` to make sure any script or content that needs to be loaded after dom ready is called

Comment: apart from everything why you dont use `$('#modal').load()` to load the content? why an ajax call with `async:false` parameter?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I used `renderAjax` in view and try with $('#modal').load() 
Still the problem persists.